# File observer using java

Tags: java, file

I am using [watch Service](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)  in order to track changes made to a file and print these changes in a text area. suppose only new data will be written(no delete and no replace) to this file is there a way to get this new data without the need to rewrite the over all file when changes done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Watch Service isn't able to tell what changed about a file. Assuming you have access to the old content of the file, you could use a diff library like java-diff-utils to find the changes. Example 1 on their wiki should match up with your issue.

[Check out](https://code.google.com/p/java-diff-utils/wiki/SampleUsage)